# How to get GWT console/development mode to generate css errors?

Tags: css, firefox, gwt

I noticed that when running GWT, it doesn't alert me of css errors such as missing/misspelled classes. Even the error console of Firefox doesn't prompt anything.

I'm skinning my web app pretty intensively, need a way to show up the css errors, any suggestion that I can try?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you using UiBinder and/or CssResource?

Comment: Hi there! I'm not using both of them yet, basically editing the css file generated when you create a new GWT project (via Eclipse plugin). The weirdest thing is Firefox is also not reporting the css errors..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order for GWT to report any CSS errors (misspelled/missing class names), you need to be including your CSSs in your GWT project via [`CssResource`](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.0/com/google/gwt/resources/client/CssResource.html) (check out [the docs](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideClientBundle.html#CssResource) for usage examples, etc). If you are using [UiBinder](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideUiBinder.html), all the CSS you declare in UiBinder's XML files are automagically converted to CssResources, so you get the benefits there too (plus, with the [Google Plugin for Eclipse](http://code.google.com/eclipse/), you'll get nice, red underlines under any misspelled/missing class names, just as you do with any other Java errors).

Note however, that CssResource obfuscates your style names by default, so it might take a bit of work to refactor your project to take that into account (again, see [the docs](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideClientBundle.html#CssResourceCookbook) for a more extensive read).

Comment: Thank you very much :) Was away thus the late reply~ Thanks for including the links, they help a lot. By the way, I'm wondering about UiBinder: How is it better than the way of building the UI in a Java Swing way?

Comment: There are many questions here on SO and on Google GWT Group about that - like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2690224/what-is-the-best-approach-towards-styling-gwt-applications